# why i cant put the mysql result in $_SESSION

Tags: php, html

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

include('CONFIG/config.php');
include('CONFIG/db.php');

$Email = $_POST['email'];
$Password = $_POST['password'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $Email;

//erroe handler
//check if the input is empty
if(empty($Email) || empty($Password)) {
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
     exit();
}else{
    $sql = "SELECT * from users where email='$Email' AND password='$Password'";
    $sql2 = "SELECT roles.id from users, roles where users.email='$Email' and roles.id = users.role_id";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $_SESSION['roleid'] = $result2;
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($resultCheck < 1){
        header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
        exit();
    }else{

        header("Location: ../dashboard.php?login=success");
        exit();
    }
}
}else{
 header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
 exit();

}
```

table stucture: roles

```
    1   idPrimary   int(11)         No  None        AUTO_INCREMENT  
    2   title   varchar(150)    utf8_unicode_ci     No  None
```

table structure: users

```
    1   idPrimary   int(11)         No  None        AUTO_INCREMENT   
    2   name    varchar(150)    utf8_unicode_ci     No  None             
    3   email   varchar(150)    utf8_unicode_ci     No  None             
    4   password    varchar(256)    utf8_unicode_ci     No  None             
    5   role_id int(11)         No  None
```

when i ran this code and print the session the $_SESSION['roleid'] print like this 
[roleid] => mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => [field_count] => [lengths] => [num_rows] => [type] => ) but the result i want is 1

Comment: You might want to store a row, by first fetching.  Otherwise you are trying to store a mysqli result.

Comment: can you please show me @Progrock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fetch the result from the `$result2`. Also, move the `$_SESSION['roleid']` to the success part. Because you need to set the session only for successfully login. See the updated code.

```
<?php 

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    include('CONFIG/config.php');
    include('CONFIG/db.php');

    $Email = $_POST['email'];
    $Password = $_POST['password'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $Email;

//erroe handler
//check if the input is empty
    if (empty($Email) || empty($Password)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
        exit();
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * from users where email='$Email' AND password='$Password'";
        $sql2 = "SELECT roles.id from users, roles where users.email='$Email' and roles.id = users.role_id";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($resultCheck < 1) {
            header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
            exit();
        } else {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2,MYSQLI_ASSOC); // Fetch the result
            $_SESSION['roleid'] = $row['id']; //Set the id to the session variable
            header("Location: ../dashboard.php?login=success");
            exit();
        }
    }
} else {
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
    exit();

}
```

See [mysqli_fetch_array()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp) function